# How can I display current and next audition in PHP using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I have created PHP function that is getting all auditions into array from database. From there I have used foreach to do, if operator that checks whenever current audition is same as server audition (broadcast radio) or is same as object from array then next audition (possible next day audition). My function works but not displaying exactly what I was expecting. It does display all objects from array rather than expecting:

```
Current:
Name
Audition Title
To time
Next:
Name
Audition Title
From time
```

So this is code I have tried on:

ARRAY:

```
ID not needed
name = audition title
Day = day number
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [0] => 15
            [username] => Anna
            [1] => Anna
            [name] => Spacer w chmurach
            [2] => Spacer w chmurach
            [audition_day] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [start_time] => 17:12:00
            [4] => 17:12:00
            [end_time] => 19:12:00
            [5] => 19:12:00
            [canceled] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [audition_type] => 2
            [7] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [0] => 16
            [username] => Marcin
            [1] => Marcin
            [name] => Kuferek z muzyką
            [2] => Kuferek z muzyką
            [audition_day] => 1
            [3] => 1
            [start_time] => 20:00:00
            [4] => 20:00:00
            [end_time] => 22:00:00
            [5] => 22:00:00
            [canceled] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [audition_type] => 2
            [7] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [0] => 17
            [username] => Monika
            [1] => Monika
            [name] => test
            [2] => test
            [audition_day] => 6
            [3] => 6
            [start_time] => 12:25:00
            [4] => 12:25:00
            [end_time] => 15:25:00
            [5] => 15:25:00
            [canceled] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [audition_type] => 1
            [7] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [0] => 18
            [username] => Maciek
            [1] => Maciek
            [name] => test
            [2] => test
            [audition_day] => 6
            [3] => 6
            [start_time] => 17:20:00
            [4] => 17:20:00
            [end_time] => 20:20:00
            [5] => 20:20:00
            [canceled] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [audition_type] => 1
            [7] => 1
        )

)
```

Then my function looks like:

```
$audition_list = array that has been made by fetching all rows from database
$auditionDJ = currently playing presenter could be "AutoDJ" that will never be in database
$auditionTitle = currently playing audition title
PDO has been applied before foreach function!
```

```
foreach($audition_list as &$row) {

            if($row["start_time"] <= $now_time) {
                if($row["end_time"] >= $now_time) {
                    echo "<div class='now'>";
                    echo "<span>Aktualnie na antenie:</span>";
                    echo "<span>".$row["username"]."</span>";
                    echo "<span>".$row["name"]."</span>";
                    echo "<span>Do: ".date("H:i", strtotime($row["end_time"]))."</span>";
                    echo "</div>";
                } else {
                    echo "<div class='now'>";
                    echo "<span>Aktualnie na antenie:</span>";
                    echo "<span>".$auditionDJ."</span>";
                    echo "<span>".$auditionTitle."</span>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
            }

            if($row["start_time"] >= $now_time) {
                if($row["end_time"] <= $now_time) {
                    echo "<div class='now'>";
                    echo "<span>Następnie:</span>";
                    echo "<span>".$auditionDJ."</span>";
                    echo "<span>".$auditionTitle."</span>";
                    echo "</div>";
                } else {
                    echo "<div class='now'>";
                    echo "<span>Następnie:</span>";
                    echo "<span>".$row["username"]."</span>";
                    echo "<span>".$row["name"]."</span>";
                    echo "<span>Od: ".date("H:i", strtotime($row["start_time"]))."</span>";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: This same question was asked by [Lance](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18100344/lance) 6 hours ago, and deleted 2 hours ago. It is not a problem when you repost a question, but please don't make multiple accounts. I suggest you delete this account and post the question as `Lance`.

Comment: The reason is that multiple accounts are used to cheat on the reputation system of Stack Overflow. That might not be your intention, but why let us think that you might do that?

Comment: Why are you retrieving all the rows from the database and then filtering on time in PHP? Just ask the database for the relevant rows.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I am cooperating with him. Yes I did post similar question but more explained. Feel free if you would like to report. His post has been deleted anyway.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular because each time I'd have to ask database for different row so in this array I have them all in one place :)